# Silverlight 4 UserControl?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight

For Silverlight 4 did TemplatedControl replace UserControl?  Because when I goto add a new item in Visual Studio 2010 that is the only thing that closely resembles a user control in the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they should both be there, are you sure the [silverlight tools for visual studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=902a7539-c4b5-4e54-b4c9-1432daabe1e8&displaylang=en) are installed correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I just installed the latest ones that went RTM either this week or last.  I will try to uninstall and reinstall...Very odd!